# How to enable profiling for a particular database in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

`db.runCommand({profile:2})` will set profiling for all databases in my MongoDB.

I have `x,y,z` databases and need to turn on profiling for `x` only

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

This will enable profiling only for your current db. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/ for more details

simple example:

```
use test1;
db.setProfilingLevel(2);
db.getProfilingLevel() // output 2

use test2 
db.getProfilingLevel() // output 0
```

Comment: It also doesn't work
Also they're idiots and changed the way to get the profile level that doesn't work as written anymore